# Update text on screen after variable changes I Xcode Swift5

Tags: swift, button, text, swift5

I started coding with Xcode 12.4 and want to change the text on my screen, when a Button was pressed and the variable of the text had changed.

Just as an little example:

```
Text(randomNumber)


Button(action: {
   changeCard()
}) {

func changeCard() {
    randomNumber = Int.random(in: 0..<maxCards)

}
```

So how can I update the changed Text on my Screen?

Comment: Use @State for randomNumber if this is SwiftUI, `@State private var randomNumber = 0`

Comment: That worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Label outlet.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var yourLabel: UILabel!
```

Change your button action to - change the label text

```
Button(action: {
   yourLabel.text = "\(changeCard())"
})
```

Now your function returns a random number.

```
func changeCard() -> Int {
   return Int.random(in: 0..<maxCards)
}
```